# How can I modify the size of Primary Key column of Varchar in a MariaDB table?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 5
Server version: 10.0.36-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu 16.04
```

My table desc:

```
MariaDB [GTX_CC]> desc SubscribedUser;
+---------------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                                       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| UserID                                      | varchar(25)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| UserName                                    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| UserStatusCode                              | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Password                                    | varchar(512) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
```

Now I want to Modify the Column length of UserID to varchar(999)

Running

```
MariaDB [GTX_CC]> ALTER TABLE SubscribedUser MODIFY UserID  varchar(999) NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

gives the following error:

```
ERROR 1063 (42000): Incorrect column specifier for column 'UserID'
```

Added>

I also tried:

```
MariaDB [GTX_CC]> ALTER TABLE SubscribedUser MODIFY UserID  varchar(999) NOT NULL ;
```

It also gives error as:

```
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Also Tried  as follows:

```
MariaDB [GTX_CC]> ALTER TABLE SubscribedUser MODIFY UserID  varchar(767) NOT NULL ;
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
MariaDB [GTX_CC]> ALTER TABLE SubscribedUser MODIFY UserID  varchar(766) NOT NULL ;
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
MariaDB [GTX_CC]>
```

What wrong in my statement? Any help , please?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? If you want auto-increment then don't use `varchar`

Comment: Now I want to Modify the Column length of UserID to varchar(999)

Comment: 999 is too long for a indexed column. 255 is max. Also use `int` instead of `varchar(...)`

Comment: UserID can't be int. Let me try with 255

Comment: MariaDB [GTX_CC]> ALTER TABLE SubscribedUser MODIFY UserID  varchar(255) NOT NULL ;
    ERROR 1833 (HY000): Cannot change column 'UserID': used in a foreign key constraint 'fk_Session_SubscribedUser1' of table 'GTX_CC.UserSession'
Now, stuck in other thing.

Comment: Is it not possible to have the modify cascade to the child table?

Comment: You have to turn foreign key checks off. then change both tables and turn it on again

Comment: I have the answer as:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13606801/10439752

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong, appears to be related to this question: [MariaDB won't create table with large VARCHAR as PRIMARY KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176482/mariadb-wont-create-table-with-large-varchar-as-primary-key).

In summary, and without wanting to repeat what's said in the above link, there is a maximum length for varchar primary keys, and the limit depends on the charset. To verify that, drop the primary key (`alter table SubscribedUser drop primary key`), alter the length of userid to your 999 (that succeeds), try to add userid as primary key (`alter table SubscribedUser add primary key(userid)`) and it'd fail with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The script will be as follows:

```
LOCK TABLES 
UserSession WRITE,
SubscribedUser WRITE;

ALTER TABLE UserSession
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_Session_SubscribedUser1,
MODIFY SubscribedUser_UserID varchar(255) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE SubscribedUser MODIFY UserID  varchar(255) NOT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE UserSession
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Session_SubscribedUser1 FOREIGN KEY (SubscribedUser_UserID)
REFERENCES SubscribedUser (UserID);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The maximum allowed char length under varchar is 255 only.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE SubscribedUser`.  I question whether that 'describe' is correct.  It should be impossible to have a `VARCHAR` as an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, *regardless of the length*.

Decide whether you want the `PRIMARY KEY` to be `AUTO_INCREMENT` or `VARCHAR`.

If you choose to have a `VARCHAR`, then think about what size is reasonable.

If you need to index a large `VARCHAR`, then see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes for the options you have.